# getting default email client mac OSX cpp

Tags: c++, macos, email

Here is my problem, i have to create an multi-platform app in c++ in wich there will be a button that will open the defqult mail client to send a mail.
So yeah, i managed to do it for windows, and now that i have to do it for mac OSX i don't seems to find anyway to do so. :/

So is there any way (syscall or something like this) to open the default mail client with a few parameters passed? (just the email adresse would be juste fine)

Thanks in advance for your answers, have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Objective-C++ try this:

```
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:my@mail.com"]]
```

Otherwise you could try to get the URL to the default email client using this function from the [Launch Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType):

```
    LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get the name of the default browser in macOS? I tried using ```LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType```, but it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, i juste used "system(open "mailto:test@test.com");" and everything worked fine. :)

Comment: Do be sure to properly shell escape **anything** you're putting in there. Otherwise I'm sending an email to `rm -rf / @evil.domain`.

Comment: What dop you meen by shell escape? D:

Comment: When you make system calls, arguments need to be properly quoted or they may show up as several commands. For example: `test@test.com"; rm -rf /;"` would be a very *bad* email address to put in without escaping.